# Xml2JaxbEncoder Leak Detection

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

*We are using spring boot 2.1.4 and netty 0.8.6.*

We are observing leak detection warnings when using `Xml2JaxbEncoder` to marshall a POJO to XML in a `Webclient`.

Client code

```
webClient
   .method(HttpMethod.GET)
   .uri(someUri)
   .body(Mono.just(requestBody), RequestType.class)
   .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
   .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
   .retrieve()
   .bodyToMono(ResponseType.class)
```

It seems as though the byte buffer should be released in the encoder on the doOnDiscard method however, the leak detection logs would suggest it is not.

```
return Flux.from(inputStream)
                .take(1)
                .concatMap(value -> encode(value, bufferFactory, elementType, mimeType, hints))
                .doOnDiscard(PooledDataBuffer.class, PooledDataBuffer::release);
```

Leak detection log from our service:

```
LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. See http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.
Recent access records: 
Created at:
    io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:334)
    io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:187)
    io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:178)
    io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.buffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:115)
    org.springframework.core.io.buffer.NettyDataBufferFactory.allocateBuffer(NettyDataBufferFactory.java:71)
    org.springframework.core.io.buffer.NettyDataBufferFactory.allocateBuffer(NettyDataBufferFactory.java:39)
    org.springframework.http.codec.xml.Jaxb2XmlEncoder.lambda$encode$2(Jaxb2XmlEncoder.java:113)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefer.subscribe(FluxDefer.java:46)
    reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:7793)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:442)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:212)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxTake$TakeFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxTake.java:371)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust.subscribe(FluxJust.java:70)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxTakeFuseable.subscribe(FluxTakeFuseable.java:45)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap.subscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:121)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart.subscribe(FluxContextStart.java:49)
    reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40)
    reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44)
    reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60)
    reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpObserver.onStateChange(HttpClientConnect.java:425)
    reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:358)
    reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.run(PooledConnectionProvider.java:562)
    reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.operationComplete(PooledConnectionProvider.java:634)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:502)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:476)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:415)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:540)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:529)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess(DefaultPromise.java:93)
    io.netty.channel.pool.FixedChannelPool$AcquireListener.operationComplete(FixedChannelPool.java:423)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:502)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:476)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:415)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:540)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:529)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess(DefaultPromise.java:93)
    io.netty.channel.pool.SimpleChannelPool.notifyHealthCheck(SimpleChannelPool.java:245)
    io.netty.channel.pool.SimpleChannelPool.doHealthCheck(SimpleChannelPool.java:226)
    io.netty.channel.pool.SimpleChannelPool.acquireHealthyFromPoolOrNew(SimpleChannelPool.java:194)
    io.netty.channel.pool.SimpleChannelPool.acquire(SimpleChannelPool.java:164)
    io.netty.channel.pool.FixedChannelPool.acquire0(FixedChannelPool.java:273)
    io.netty.channel.pool.FixedChannelPool.access$300(FixedChannelPool.java:40)
    io.netty.channel.pool.FixedChannelPool$3.run(FixedChannelPool.java:247)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:495)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

After a period of time this accumulates in an OutOfDirectMemoryError exception in the application.

```
io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError: failed to allocate 16777216 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 1023410183, max: 1029177344)
```

Is there a known issue with the Xml2JaxbEncoder? Is there anything we are doing wrong in our code? Any support would be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest upgrading to 2.1.6 of Spring Boot and see if it still happens (or wait for 2.1.7 which is around the corner).

Comment: there has been issues about this on github, so pls upgrade https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1634

Comment: bumping to 2.1.6 has resolved these issues. Thanks for providing a link to the reactor issues. They were very useful.

Comment: you are welcome @MichaelMcFadyen good luck!